# How i can Debug variable in Django on web page?

Tags: python, django

in JavaScript i can do

```
console.log(variable-name)
```

work good.

what options are in Django ?

Comment: You should read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Answer (score 5):

There is a [django-debug-toolbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar) from which you can track SQL query, session, request and so on.

Comment: hi @FoxMaSk nice plugin but still my question is not satisfy .! How to inspect variable on webpage ?

Comment: like suggested shivan raptor, the standard way is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/ but specially for a webpage i will suggest to make your own template tag `{log_my_var:variable_name:variable_value}` (for exemple) which will write the name and value of my variable in the log file

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which values are passed, you can add

```
import logging
logging.warning(variable-name)
```

in your django code.
The message is printed to the console.

If you just want to inspect a variable, just add
`{{ variable-name }}` in the beginning of the page.
If you don't see a value, your variable is empty or variable name is mis-spelled.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a simple way in your code to "spit out" the value of a variable.

`print variable_name` will cause the variable to show up in your django developer server and you can easily see it.
I would tend to discourage this behavior because it tends to mean that you aren't testing your code properly. I'd build a test for the area in question, then you can try many different possibilities. Start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/